# Swift: Retrieving data from a Struct

Tags: swift, struct

1. I have defined a struct like so:

```
struct User {
    var ID: String!
    var firstName: String!
    var lastName: String!
    var email: String!
    var role: String!
    
}
```

2. Casting data to a different view controller

```
var userDetails = [User]()
..//

print(userDetails)
//[Project.User(ID: Optional("abcgdqwe"), firstName: Optional("Raul"), lastName: Optional("test"), email: Optional("xyz@xyz.com"), role: Optional("admin"))]
```

**Question**

How do i access the data inside userDetails??

I tried this:

```
print(userDetails.email) // ERROR: Value of type '[User]' has no member 'email'
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`userDetails` isn't one `User`... it's a `[User]` (a.k.a. `Array<User>`). Asking an array for its email doesn't make any sense.

You have to pick one of the users in the array, and ask specifically for their e-mail.

Comment: Thanks! .. Since i just had one user here userDetails[0].email worked like a charm. Appreciate the clarity :)

Comment: @r2Dragon Try to do your array manipulations in a way that doesn't make assumptions about their size, whenever possible. In your example, subscripting the `userDetails` array with index `0` will crash if the array is empty (which may or may not be possible, depending on how you obtained it to begin with)